# How to solve for the intensity of a plane wave through an aperture

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, visible-light, radar

The commonly cited equations for the intensity of light intensity through an aperture express the intensity as proportional to a solution rather than absolutely equal to a value.

For example, in [Wikipedia discussion on apertures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraunhofer_diffraction_equation#Apertures), the equation for the Intensity of the field from a rectangular aperture is

\begin{align}
I(x, y)
& \propto \operatorname{sinc}^2\left(\frac{\pi W x}{\lambda R}\right)\operatorname{sinc}^2\left(\frac{ \pi H y}{\lambda R}\right)\\
& \propto \operatorname{sinc}^2\left(\frac{k W x}{2 R}\right)\operatorname{sinc}^2\left(\frac{k H y}{2 R}\right)
\end{align}

Given the intensity of the field entering the aperture of $I_{0}$ in units of Watts per meter^2 and propagation in a lossless medium is the exact solution

\begin{align}
I(x, y)
&  = I_{0} \operatorname{sinc}^2\left(\frac{\pi W x}{\lambda R}\right)\operatorname{sinc}^2\left(\frac{ \pi H y}{\lambda R}\right)\\
\end{align}